# Openlayers3 show layers by selecting specific features

Tags: openlayers

I have a map with the possibility of selecting some layers to be shown. Layers are contained in a variable "layers" as following

```
    var layers = [

        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            name: 'OpenStreetMap',
            visible: true,

        }),

        new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
                    }),
                    url: 'repository/prova5.geojson',
                    attributions: [
                        new ol.Attribution({
                            html: 'Prova 5'
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                name: 'Prova 5',
                visible: false,

            }),

    new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
                        defaultDataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
                    }),
                    url: 'repository/prova7.geojson',
                    attributions: [
                        new ol.Attribution({
                            html: 'Prova 7'
                        })
                    ]
                }),
                name: 'Prova 7',
                visible: false,
            })
];
```

By clicking on checkbox on the menu aside I can show each distinctive layer, setting the visibility from false to true. So up to here everything works fine.

Here's the problem.
I also need in the menu aside one select that gives me the possibility of showing the layers according to one single feature present in the geojson files. Let's say that this feature is "Species" (it is contained in my geojson files).

I tried to write the select in simple HTML as a trial, and via jQuery I get the value selected corresponding to the species I want. This event should trigger the function **forEachFeature** to get the features in the geojson file (doesn't it work like fetching an array?); once fetched the feature I want compare it with my selected value. Then it should get all layers sources that contain the species selected and put them in a temporary layer that becomes visible.

The code is as following, but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var selectedSpecies = '';
        $("select.species").change(function(){

        var selectedSpecies = $(".species option:selected").val();
        console.log(selectedSpecies);
    });

    if (selectedSpecies) {
        layers.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
            var geojsonAnimal = feature.get("Species");
            console.log('Species ' + geojsonAnimal); //serve per il debug

            if(geojsonAnimal == selectedSpecies){
                console.log('Trovato animale'); 
                tmpLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
            } else {
                console.log('Non trovato!'); 
            }
        });

    }
    // Create a blank tmp layer
    var tmpLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector()
    });
    map.addLayer(tmpLayer);


    if(tmpLayer.getSource().length > 0){
         tmpLayer.setVisible(true);
    }

});
```

Actually I can see in the console the selected variable, but for instance I cannot see anything even with the command

```
console.log('Species ' + geojsonAnimal);
```

This fact makes me thinking that even the way I apply the forEachfeature() command is wrong.

Can anybody help me?
The full source is downloadable [here](http://www.elenapolitiwebdesign.com/repository/test_map.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is multiple errors in your code:

- first, on select change event you don't go through all you feature so it's normal you never this the result of

> `console.log('Species ' + geojsonAnimal);`

- second, you can't do `layers.getSource()` layers is an array, not an
  ol.layer.Layer

Fixing these 2 issues, your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select.species").change(function() {

    var selectedSpecies = $(".species option:selected").val();
    console.log(selectedSpecies);

    if (selectedSpecies) {

      layers.forEach(function(layer) {

        if (!(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector)) {
          return
        }        

        layer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature){
          var geojsonAnimal = feature.get("Species");
          console.log('Species ' + geojsonAnimal); //serve per il debug

          if(geojsonAnimal == selectedSpecies){
            console.log('Trovato animale'); 
            tmpLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
          } else {
            console.log('Non trovato!'); 
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });

  // Create a blank tmp layer
  var tmpLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
  });
  map.addLayer(tmpLayer);

  if(tmpLayer.getSource().length > 0){
    tmpLayer.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seem not working. Actually I should see something of the feature I fetched in the console, as I wrote my code on the example below and there I could see layer vector features in the console. Actually I need the console only to check if the procedure is working step by step. The final result should be showing the layers containing the species I search for. https://plnkr.co/edit/DeaVFGBK11jKCT3yHAVd?p=info